# Apply the same animation to a group of objects

Tags: rendering, animation, scripting, export

I am new to blender and am using it to create turntable animations of 3D objects. I have a lot of objects and using the same animation for all objects one by one manually is very time consuming and tedious. Is there any way I can automate this process?

I cannot use python scripts (with bpy) as I am struggling to install bpy with pip after recent updates. So is there no other way apart from python to automate this?

Comment: There is a much better option than animating every single object. Just add an empty to the scene and parent the camera to it. Now simply animate the z-rotation of the empty and your camera will follow. (I know that this is not what you asked for but leaving this just in case it helps you out)

Comment: I was just about to say that in a comment. The other question is why can't you use python scripts? - Python comes with Blender so there's no need to install anything else. You just write and run your scripts in Blender.

Comment: @Akshay2005 - Thanks for the suggestion, yes I use Empty to do turntables but I have to import an obj every time and animate it to the same filename. I have over a lot of obj files so that is not viable.

Comment: @JohnEason Without installing bpy, I cannot import bpy. 
'Python comes with Blender so there's no need to install anything else' - How do I import bpy and how do I run scripts? Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: @JohnEason - Just found the scripting workspace. Thanks. So stupid of me not to notice.

Comment: You don't animate the object to make a turntable, you animate the camera, it's much simpler and it doesn't require any scripting or redundant animation copy-pasting.

Comment: If you wanted to have a group of objects follow an object's animation, you would just parent these objects to the animated one.

Comment: You don't need to install bpy unless you want to execute python scripts outside of Blender. Which is something that you only do when you want to develop something consequent like an addon, and you want to use your preferred IDE or text editor instead of Blender's text editor. But for simple one-time usage scripts, Blender's script editor is more than enough and no package installation is required. But again : you don't need to script anything for a turntable.

Comment: @L0Lock - I create one turntable animation from one object. Then I remove the object and import another. Then I create another turntable for that object. This continues for all the objects (500+) that I have. This does not make sense right?

Comment: As L0Lock says you could make the camera rotate instead of your object. But you could also give the exact same action to all the object, without recreating it. The only tedious part is to import each object one by one, is it the thing that you're trying to automate?

Comment: @moonboots yes I was trying to automate loading the object and deleting it after the animation has been created. I found a way to do it - probably my question was not phrased correctly, which is why the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects share the same animation you just have to instance the animation data via linking:

Select all the objects and in the menu Object select Link../Animation Data.

That Will link animation data of the active Object to the selection.

Being linked, any further change in the animation Will affect all the objects.